# Azure app services, multithreaded vs multi instance

Tags: azure, connection, webjob

I have a question with a decision a previously employed architect has made in our deployment plan.

Currently our software has allot of outbound connections. In order to support the load (which is not too impressive to be fair) it has been chosen to have 1 app service plan, with 2 app services that are each filled to the max with webjobs of the same application that simply reads blob storage and posts the content to both the same and different endpoints. Each webjob is configured to post to a particular endpoint which can be the same as another.

Now I do not have much experience with azure, so I do not know if there is a particular limitation in the way webjobs are hosted that this solves.

I wish to simplify this deployment plan by simply reducing the amount of webjobs back to one and make it run multithreaded.

But I'm a little worried that by doing so, I am limiting the amount of connections possible from that webjob to both the same endpoint and in total.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (the information in) articles like this one might have had something to do with that choice: [Starving outgoing connections on Windows Azure Web Sites](https://www.freekpaans.nl/2015/08/starving-outgoing-connections-on-windows-azure-web-sites/). Please be advised this is a relatively old article.

A lot has changed since, although there still are some limitations: [App Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

> IP Connections for...
>   Free:         600
>   Shared:       600
>   Basic:        Depends on instance size
>   Standard:     Depends on instance size
>   Premium (v2): Depends on instance size
>   Isolated:     16,000
>
> *The maximum IP connections are per instance and depend on the instance size:
>
>   - 1,920 per B1/S1/P1V2 instance
>
>   - 3,968 per B2/S2/P2V2 instance
>
>   - 8,064 per B3/S3/P3V2 instance.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I've read the article you linked and the summary of currently documented connections.

But all these things are documented around the app service plan. Which (i hope) is the actual limiting factor.

What im worried about is that instead of having 100 web jobs running on the same app service plan, and only 1 web jobs running multithreaded. Would somehow limit the amount of connections I can open.